# how to create a keyboard shortcut for split view (duplicate of the same file) in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext

I want to have a keyboard shortcut key for opening the same file in another tab.

this can be done using File>Split view

[image]

How can I create a keyboard shortcut for this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+u", "ctrl+s"],
  "command": "clone_file",
  "args": {"add_to_selection": true} },
```

BTW, I found the command's name by typing sublime.log_commands(True) into the console. See OdatNurd's excellent video on this: [P101-03 Tools of the Trade: Harnessing the power of the console!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cqbw2XgNBoQ)